# What are the C# Access Modifiers, and how do they compare? Is there a decent visual diagram?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

**Research:** I have been read the [MSDN C# Access Modifiers reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) which provides definitions, but few examples. The definitions are correct, but would be much easier to understand if they were presented visually in a diagram. Searching SO I found several questions discussing special circumstances with modifiers, or comparing one modifier to another, but not all modifiers, and not visually. I also searched the web for "C# Access Modifier Diagrams" and was able to find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25078/C-Access-Modifiers-Quick-Reference) quick reference, which contained some examples and also a diagram, but was not as clear as I would have liked. I was not able to find an all-in one source for this information.

**Question**
I'd like to find an all in one guide to C# Access Modifiers that shows the following using definitions, code examples, and visual aids such as a diagram.

- What are the different Access Modifiers in C#?
- What is the scope of each modifier and how do they compare?
- How do they apply to internal classes, external classes, inherited classes, and non-inherited classes?

Comment: My intention was to improve upon the answers found in google search. I could not find a good visual representation of the access modifiers.

Comment: I thought that the diagram below would be useful in a community wiki, as I see multiple questions attempting to compare two access modifiers to eachother. I can't submit a wiki answer without a proper question.

Comment: That in no way relaxes the quality standards for questions.  You need to ask a quality, on topic question if you want to post an answer to it.  That you want to post an answer doesn't mean the question doesn't need to follow the rules.

Comment: @Servy which rule does this question break? When I approached this problem I had these exact questions, and wasn't able to find an all encompassing answer that explained the access modifiers not just with definitions, but also visually and with examples. I'll gladly improve the question if I can.

Comment: The question is both Too Broad, and doesn't demonstrate sufficient research effort when asking a question about information that is already readily available.

Comment: "Write an entire guide for me" is *textbook* Too Broad.  And the fact that your question is explicitly asking for information *that you've already said you've found* is a major problem.  If you've already found detailed definitions of each modifier, then you should have no need to ask for the definition of each modifier, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback from the SO users and would delete my question if able. I had hoped to provide a good reference for understanding access modifiers using examples and visually, with no rep bonus to myself since it was marked as a wiki answer, but I have obviously not used SO in the correct way to provide this. I was not able to find exactly what I wanted on the internet, so I came up with a comprehensive clear example that is useful to me.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [MSDN C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx):

In c# there are 5 levels of access modifiers. Listed from most to least restrictive, they are as follows:

1. Private

   - Access is limited to the containing type.
2. Protected

   - Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.
3. Internal

   - Access is limited to the current assembly.
4. Protected Internal

   - Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class.
5. Public

   - Access is not restricted.

I created the following diagram to visually show the scope of these modifiers as it affects multiple assemblies, classes, and derived classes.

In this diagram, there are 5 differently colored access modifier groupings. For each grouping, if the BaseClassMember or NestedClass is modified with the corresponding access modifier, then only classes within that group have access to it. Classes outside do not.

For example, If BaseClassMember  is modified as "Protected", then only the classes within the orange Protected group can access BaseClassMember . These classes are BaseClass, InternalInheritedClass, and ExternalInheritedClass. Classes outside of this line do not have access to BaseClassMember.

[image: Access Modifiers Diagram]
**Code for Testing**

**Assembly1**

```
namespace Assembly1
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public int PublicMember;
        protected internal int ProtectedInternalMember;
        internal int InternalMember;
        protected int ProtectedMember;
        private int PrivateMember;

        public class PublicClass { }
        protected internal class ProtectedInternalClass { }
        internal class InternalClass { }
        protected class ProtectedClass { }
        private class PrivateClass { }
    }

    public class InternalClass
    {
        public InternalClass()
        {
            BaseClass class0Instance = new BaseClass();
            var publicMember = class0Instance.PublicMember;
            var protectedInternalMember = class0Instance.ProtectedInternalMember;
            var internalMember = class0Instance.InternalMember;
            var protectedMember = "not accessible";
            var privateMember = "not accessible";

            var publicClass = new BaseClass.PublicClass();
            var protectedInternalClass = new BaseClass.ProtectedInternalClass();
            var internalClass = new BaseClass.InternalClass();
            var protectedClass = "not accessible";
            var privateClass = "not accessible";
        }
    }

    public class InternalInheritedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public InternalInheritedClass()
        {
            var publicMember = this.PublicMember;
            var protectedInternalMember = this.ProtectedInternalMember;
            var internalMember = this.InternalMember;
            var protectedMember = this.ProtectedMember;
            var privateMember = "not accessible";

            var publicClass = new BaseClass.PublicClass();
            var protectedInternalClass = new BaseClass.ProtectedInternalClass();
            var internalClass = new BaseClass.InternalClass();
            var protectedClass = new BaseClass.ProtectedClass();
            var privateClass = "not accessible";
        }
    }
}
```

**Assembly2**

```
using Assembly1;
namespace Assembly2
{
    public class ExternalClass
    {
        public ExternalClass()
        {
            BaseClass class0Instance = new BaseClass();
            var publicMember = class0Instance.PublicMember;
            var protectedInternalMember = "not accessible";
            var internalMember = "not accessible";
            var protectedMember = "not accessible";
            var privateMember = "not accessible";

            var publicClass = new BaseClass.PublicClass();
            var protectedInternalClass = "not accessible";
            var internalClass = "not accessible";
            var protectedClass = "not accessible";
            var privateClass = "not accessible";
        }
    }

    public class ExternalInheritedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public ExternalInheritedClass()
        {
            var publicMember = this.PublicMember;
            var protectedInternalMember = this.ProtectedInternalMember;
            var internalMember = "not accessible";
            var protectedMember = this.ProtectedMember;
            var privateMember = "not accessible";

            var publicClass = new BaseClass.PublicClass();
            var protectedInternalClass = new BaseClass.ProtectedInternalClass();
            var internalClass = "not accessible";
            var protectedClass = new BaseClass.ProtectedClass();
            var privateClass = "not accessible";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for your patience. I understand what you are saying now. I've updated the diagram.

Comment: That's much clearer, thank you, I'll remove my comments.